# Print a list of tuples as a string

Tags: python, tuples, string-concatenation

I have a list of tuples

```
[
 ('User: ', '<@268326653795500044>, ', 1), 
 ('User: ', '<@381118832963616779>, ', 3), 
 ('User: ', '<@510489897790996492>, ', 1)
]
```

This is how I create the list of tuples

```
curs.execute('SELECT userID, strike FROM user WHERE strike != 0')
records = curs.fetchall()

rows = []

for row in records:
  string = 'User: ', f'<@{row[0]}>, ', row[1]
  rows.append(string)
print(rows)
```

That I want to print as a string:
String: User: <@268326653795500044>, 1

Comment: Use `''.join(that_tuple)` or why not just `string = f'User: <@{row[0]}> {row[1]}'`

Comment: I just realized that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
data = [('User: ', '<@268326653795500044>, ', 1), 
('User: ','<@381118832963616779>, ', 3), 
('User: ', '<@510489897790996492>, ', 1)]


for i in data:
    print(f"{' '.join(map(str,i))}")
```

You could just use `.join()` as the comments pointed out. You do have ints in your tuple so they would have to be converted to strings to then join with the other string values in your tuple.

#### Ouput:

```
User:  <@268326653795500044>,  1
User:  <@381118832963616779>,  3
User:  <@510489897790996492>,  1
```

Answer (score 1):

It's only a list of tuples because that is what you are creating by using `,` rather than `+` for concatenation:

```py
curs.execute('SELECT userID, strike FROM user WHERE strike != 0')
records = curs.fetchall()
    
rows = []
    
for row in records:
   string = 'User: ' +  f'<@{row[0]}>, ' + row[1] # now we have a string instead of a tuple
   rows.append(string)
    
print(rows)
```

As a comment pointed out you are using an f string, so why not go all the way:

```py
string = f'User: <@{row[0]}>, {row[1]}' # now we have a
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
string_list = []
for x,y,z in records:
   str = x+':'+y+','+str(z)
   string_list.append(str)
```

Edit: Avoid indexing as mentioned by Sushant in comment

Comment: Unpacking ``for x, y, z in records``, to avoid indexing..

Comment: @Sushanth Just curious, why would you want to avoid indexing?